# Best Practices for migrating SSL web applications to a different server

Tags: ssl

Migrating some Tomcat/Apache applications from Mac OS X to Linux (RHEL 6), and was wondering what the best practices are for using the existing SSL certs.  This migration is not a one to one, meaning previously I may have had mac-server1 running `https://mac-server1.org` and mac-server2 running `https://mac-server2.org`, but now I will have Linux-server1 in a load-balanced pair (using a Citrix Netscaler) with Linux-server2 and `https://mac-server1.org` & `https://mac-server2.org` will be running on both Linux boxes.

Should all the SSL termination be handled at the load balancer to simplify this?  What if I wanted to install the certs directly to both Linux boxes, how do I avoid having a CN/name mismatch?  Would I need multiple NICs with a different IP for each?

How does an SSL certificate verify that the CN on the cert matches the hostname of the server it resides on?  Does it use DNS, or some underlying system call/library function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Depends on your security requirements.  Doing it at the load balancer level surely simplifies things.  Reduced CPU usage on the servers.. fewer places to update expired certificates.
- The cert's CN and the hostname and IPs have no bearing on any mismatch.  The *client* makes that determination, not the server.
- No you would not need multiple NICs and different IPs.
- SSL certificates don't verify the CN with the hostname.  The only verification that happens is that your key can decrypt the signed certificate.  If it can't, then obviously it can't pass the certificate on to clients.
- It uses none of those, the client (web browser) does that.

Comment: So the browser just checks that the host portion of the URL/URI matches the CN in the site's certificate?  So I could have a sever called serverA, and create a DNS host record where I map the IP address of serverA to the hostname `www.foobar.com` and if I have a cert with CN=www.foobar.com installed on serverA, the Browser will be satisfied and not complain?

Comment: The statement about multiple NICs and IPs is because you cannot do NameBased Virtual Hosting with SSL reliably, since SSL is higher in the stack than HTTP, the default SSL host will always receive the request before Apache or Tomcat has a chance to read the HTTP Host attribute.  How do you suggest I work around that when moving multiple SSL web apps from multiple hosts to a single load-balanced host pair?

Comment: As for the DNS to www.foobar.com, yes; that's exactly how it works.  For multiple domains on the same system there are many options available.  [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), using separate ports with a load balancer in front (which may require multiple IPs on the load balancer), get a multi-domain (UCC) certificate...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding CN/name mismatch, one thing to bear in mind is that you set the ServerName in Apache appropriately.

If you have multiple VirtualHost declarations on the same IP, make sure they use the same certificate, or be willing to require clients to use Service Name Indication  (with XP 'officially' dead, that's a lot closer, but not close enough for my own comfort).